# Is there a "natural" grading of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2 + y^2 - 1)$ over $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, numerical-methods

Let $f = x^2 + y^2 - 1\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$, $S^1=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid f(x,y) = 0\}$ and $I = (f)\subseteq \mathbb{R}[x,y]$. Is there a "natural" nontrivial grading of the coordinate ring of $S^1$, $$\mathbb{R}[x,y]/I$$
over $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$, such that there are elements of every degree? From what I gather, there is not such a grading induced by the standard grading (by polynomial degree) in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ since $f$ is not homogenous with respect to this grading. For a little bit of context, my knowledge of algebra is minimal and I encountered this problem in a numerical analysis setting.

The goal is to find an analogous notion of a Lagrange Interpolation polynomial, but on $S^1$. I.E., I would like to have notion of a polynomial $p\colon S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ with degree $d$ so that I can find a polynomial of degree $n-1$ that interpolates a function $g\colon S^1\to \mathbb{R}$ through a set of $n$ points $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}\subseteq S^1$. Ideally, an element of degree $d$ on $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/I$ would locally behave like a polynomial in one variable of degree $d$ while still maintaining nice global properties, but any example grading would be interesting to play with.

Maybe there is already an established way to do this, but I was hoping that if I can find a grading for the coordinate ring, then there would be a natural notion of a polynomial on $S^1$ of a certain degree by restricting representatives of elements of the coordinate ring to their evaluation on $S^1$. I was also hoping that the idea might generalize to other varieties, or even implicitly on manifolds, in a natural way.

Comment: Every ring has a trivial grading concentrated in degree 0. If this is not "natural" for you, you need to specify what you are looking for.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Of course, sorry.

Comment: Since $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ is standard (even though some authors don't follow this standard for some reason), I have removed the unnecessary $\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ from the question.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Please change it back. What is “standard” in your part of the world is definitely not standard in the US. It is not just “some authors.”

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg  It is appropriate to edit a post to fix grammar or spelling, or to correct "obvious" typographical errors.  It may even be appropriate to edit a post to include information that the original author left in the comments.  It is **not** appropriate to edit a post in order to change the conventions which are used.  In this case, your edit was inappropriate, and potentially confusing, as a significant number of mathematicians do not include $0$ in the set of natural numbers.

Comment: Thanks @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, I think I get the idea. I might try to post a solution later if it feels appropriate.